# Facebook Audience Network ads App crashes when Interstitial ad is Dismissed

Tags: java, android, facebook

I have a problem with Facebook Audience network mediation . When I changed it to the latest release (implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.1.0' and implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:5.1.0.0') my app crashes when I close the Interstitial ad.  But when im offline my app works fine. What seems to be the problem? thank you for answering.

Here is the logcat (error):

```
 2018-12-18 17:57:33.115 186-186/? E/BufferQueueCore: 
[com.packagename.myapp/com.facebook.ads.AudienceNetworkActivity] 
setDefaultMaxBufferCount: setting count to 3, previous is 2 
2018-12-18 17:57:35.317 1605-1605/? E/Zygote: no v2
2018-12-18 17:57:35.327 186-186/? E/BufferQueueCore: 
[com.sec.android.app.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher] 
setDefaultMaxBufferCount: setting count to 3, previous is 2 
2018-12-18 17:57:36.418 1605-1605/? E/CII: IMSUtility: 
isIMSServiceEnabled. VoLTE CSC feature disabled.
2018-12-18 17:57:36.789 1605-1634/? E/Mms/DbUtils: rebuild done, 0 
drafts,Elapsed time : 26.428225 ms
2018-12-18 17:57:36.859 1635-1635/? E/Zygote: no v2
 2018-12-18 17:57:36.959 1635-1635/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find 
 provider info for com.samsung.android.coreapps.easysignup.public
2018-12-18 17:57:36.959 1635-1635/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find 
provider info for com.samsung.android.coreapps.easysignup.public
2018-12-18 17:57:36.959 1635-1635/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find 
provider info for com.samsung.android.coreapps.easysignup.public
2018-12-18 17:57:36.969 1635-1635/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find 
provider info for com.samsung.android.coreapps.easysignup.public
2018-12-18 17:57:36.969 1635-1635/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find 
provider info for com.samsung.android.coreapps.easysignup.public
 2018-12-18 17:57:36.999 1635-1635/? E/CII: IMSUtility: 
 isIMSServiceEnabled. VoLTE CSC feature disabled.
 2018-12-18 17:57:44.316 1414-1975/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 2099 [12-18 
 17:57:44.320]
2018-12-18 17:57:51.003 210-1672/? E/NetlinkEvent: 
 NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'LABEL' not found
2018-12-18 17:57:51.003 210-1672/? E/NetlinkEvent: 
NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found
2018-12-18 17:57:59.781 210-1672/? E/NetlinkEvent: 
NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'LABEL' not found
2018-12-18 17:57:59.781 210-1672/? E/NetlinkEvent: 
NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found
2018-12-18 17:58:06.167 1794-1794/? E/SignalClusterView: 
setSlotFocusVisible : subId 5
2018-12-18 17:58:06.167 1794-1794/? E/SignalClusterView: 
  setSlotFocusVisible : subId 5
  018-12-18 16:20:44.098 1414-1975/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 
 1905 [12-18 16:20:44.109]
 2018-12-18 16:20:49.363 210-1672/? E/NetlinkEvent: 
 NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'LABEL' not found
 2 018-12-18 16:20:49.363 210-1672/? E/NetlinkEvent: 
 NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found
```

Here is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ActivityMainBinding mBinding;
private com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    interstitialAd = new com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd(this, "FACEBOOK_ID"); 
    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new InterstitialAdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInterstitialDisplayed(Ad ad) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onInterstitialDismissed(Ad ad) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {
        }
    });
    interstitialAd.loadAd();

    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
}
public void load(View view){
    animateButtonWidth();
    fadeOutTextAndSetProgressDialog();
    nextAction();
}
private void animateButtonWidth(){
    ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(mBinding.mainbtn.getMeasuredWidth(),getFinalWidth());
    anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            int value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = mBinding.mainbtn.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.width = value;
            mBinding.mainbtn.requestLayout();
        }
    });
    anim.setDuration(250);
    anim.start();
}
private void fadeOutTextAndSetProgressDialog(){
    mBinding.maintext.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(250).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            showProgressDialog();
        }
    }).start();
}
private void showProgressDialog(){
    mBinding.progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    mBinding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
private void nextAction(){
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            revealButton();
            fadeOutProgressDialog();
            delayedStartNextActivity();
        }
    },4000);
}
private void revealButton(){
    mBinding.mainbtn.setElevation(0f);
    mBinding.revealView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    int x = mBinding.revealView.getWidth();
    int y = mBinding.revealView.getHeight();
    int startX = (int) (getFinalWidth() / 2 + mBinding.mainbtn.getX());
    int startY = (int) (getFinalWidth() / 2 + mBinding.mainbtn.getY());
    float radius = Math.max(x,y) * 1.2f;
    Animator reveal = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(mBinding.revealView,startX,startY,getFinalWidth(),radius);
    reveal.setDuration(350);
    reveal.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            finish();
        }
    });
    reveal.start();
}
private void fadeOutProgressDialog(){
    mBinding.progressBar.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(200).start();
}
private void delayedStartNextActivity() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (interstitialAd != null && interstitialAd.isAdLoaded()) {
                interstitialAd.show();
            } else {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
            }
        }
    },100);
}
private int getFinalWidth(){
    return (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.get_width);
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (interstitialAd != null) {
        interstitialAd.destroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```